# How do I delete a specific number in an Local Storage array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm making a webapp with a grades calculator where I can Add grades and delete them. They are saved in a Local Storage. When trying to delete a specifig grade it deletes the grade recently added. How can I specifically delete an int in an Array?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Grade-Calculator</h2>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(g,idx) in grades" :key="idx">
          {{idx+1}}. Grade : {{g}}
          <button v-on:click="delGrade()">Delete</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div>
        <label>New Grade:</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="newGrade" />
        <button v-on:click="addGrade()">Add</button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <p>Average: {{ calcAvg() | round}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<!-- The Script-->
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    grades: [],
    newGrade: null,
    avg: 0,
    formattedNumber: ""
  }),
  name: "Home",
  props: {},

  methods: {
    delGrade: function() {
      var idx = this.grades.indexOf(this.grades);
      this.grades.splice(idx);
      localStorage.removeItem("grades");
      localStorage.setItem("grades", this.grades);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.grades = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("grades")) || [];
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: `this.grades.indexOf(this.grades);` makes no sense. The array doesn't contain itself as an element.

Answer (score 1):

First you need the grade to delete in `delGrade(gradeToDelete)` and once you have it (and its index by `this.grades.indexOf(gradeToDelete)`) you can work with the index.

Furthermore, I think .splice needs a deleteCount to remove the element at the index. Try changing `this.grades.splice(idx);` to `this.grades.splice(idx, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your data looks like integers in an array. In which they will be stored like the example below.

```
let grades = [8, 9, 5, 6, 3];
localStorage.setItem('grades', JSON.stringify(grades));
```

To remove a single key from the array, first parse it back to an array format and then use the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method create a new array without the grade that you want to remove.

```
let gradeToRemove = 5;
let storedGrades = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('grades'));
let newGrades = storedGrades.filter(grade => grade !== gradeToRemove);
localStorage.setItem('grades', JSON.stringify(newGrades));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should provide id, which you want to delete from array

```
 <button v-on:click="delGrade(idx)">Delete</button>
```

then you should receive that id and use it

```
    delGrade: function(idToDelete) {
      this.grades.splice(idToDelete, 1);
      localStorage.removeItem("grades"); // it is not necessary, coz you will override all key grades in next line
      localStorage.setItem("grades", this.grades);
    }
```

Comment: I prefer this one over mine, because of avoiding the the search for an index. if you have one int serveral times, using the `.indexOf`-way you will always delete the first occurrence. aleksey's approach avoids that. making things a bit more 'future-proof'